# Bootstrap Modal closing when any modal inside is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I am using basic bootstrap modal inside which there is a summernote text area. 
 Problem is when I click on the insert picture button in summernote, it again opens a modal to choose the picture, but if I click on the modal close button of the summernote picture modal without choosing the picture, it closes the main modal too. 
I don't want to close the main modal when modal close of the picture modal is clicked. Any help would be appreciated....

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Check that these modals do not share the same `id` attribute
- Also check that they do not share the same `name` attribute
- you can give them separate names manually (like numbers: `modal1`)
- you can also name them automatically with your server-side language when creating them, or with JavaScript upon load, but remember to reference these names correctly in the references, buttons & functions that close them.

Answer (score 0):

@argon 's solution didn't work for me.

But I found this solution (provided [here](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/1512)):

```
('#HtmlContent').summernote( {
  dialogsInBody: true,
});
```